# Servlet Exception: invalid driver class name

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i am a beginner in jsp, i was trying to list the users from the database,
here is my code:

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" 
    import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>InfoVisual</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<sql:setDataSource var="chh_cw" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/chh-cw"
     user="root"  password="1234"/>
<sql:query dataSource="${chh_cw}" var="result">
select DispUserName from user_mst;
</sql:query>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
   <th>District</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
   <td><c:out value="${row.DispUserName}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
    <form method="post" action="Login">
        <div class="login">

            Select District
            <select name="district">

            </select>
            <br />Username <input type="text" name="username"/>
            <br />Password <input type="password" name="pswd"/>
            <br /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i referred to the site tutorialspoint: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm

but i am getting this error(it's quite  long, sorry for that):

```
   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Login.jsp at line 17

14: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
15: </head>
16: <body>
17: <sql:setDataSource var="chh_cw" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
18:      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/chh-cw"
19:      user="root"  password="1234"/>
20: <sql:query dataSource="${chh_cw}" var="result">


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: In &lt;driver&gt;, invalid driver class name: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:908)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:126)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.DataSourceWrapper.setDriverClassName(DataSourceWrapper.java:55)
    org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.SetDataSourceTagSupport.doStartTag(SetDataSourceTagSupport.java:111)
    org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fsetDataSource_005f0(Login_jsp.java:152)
    org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

here is my project structure:
[image]

sorry this question became too long. please guide me through this problem. Thanx :)

Comment: Remove one of the driver jars.

Comment: yes i did but still getting the error, the new error i am updating, please wait

Comment: It just reminds me of fingernails on a chalkboard to use SQL inside a JSP. Sets my soul on edge.

Comment: i have removed the extra mysql jar, but this doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Have you tried reading one of the posted answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have not included the MySQL driver in your project. It is clearly stated in the stacktrace:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

For web application projects, make sure to drop all the third party libraries (i.e. jars) in WEB-INF/lib folder, nowhere else.

Also, by your image, seems that you have two MySQL Drivers. Use one only, get rid of the other.

More info:

- [ClassNotFoundException/NoClassDefFoundError in my Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23905333/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add mysql connector jar to deployment assembly of the project. To do this, right click the project and open "Deployment Assembly" tab. Then add the Jar into the assembly.