# ClassNotFoundException/NoClassDefFoundError in my Java web application

Tags: java, jar, java-war

I developer a web application using Java. When I deploy it to my application server (Jetty, Tomcat, JBoss, GlassFish, etc.) throws an error. I can see this error message in the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Or

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Posted this kind-of general Q/A for typical `ClassNotFoundException` on web applications. Edit the question/answer accordingly.

Comment: I just wrote two seconds before you! sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does this mean?

First, let's see the meaning of [`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html):

> Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:
>
> - The `forName` method in class `Class`.
> - The `findSystemClass` method in class `ClassLoader`.
> - The `loadClass` method in class `ClassLoader`.
>
> but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.

Usually, this happens when trying to open a connection manually in this form:

```
String jdbcDriver = "...'; //name of your driver
Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
```

Or when you refer to a class that belongs to an external library and *strangely* this class cannot be loaded when the application server tries to deploy the application.

Let's see the meaning of [`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) (emphasis mine):

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a `ClassLoader` instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
>
> **The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found**.

The last part says it all: the class existed at compile time i.e. when I compiled the application through my IDE, but it is not available at runtime i.e. when the application is deployed.

---

> how can I fix it?

In Java web applications, all third party libraries used by your application must go in WEB-INF/lib folder. Make sure that all the necessary libraries (jars) are placed there. You can check this easily:

```
- <webapp folder>
  - WEB-INF
    - lib
      + jar1
      + jar2
      + ...
  - META-INF
  - <rest of your folders>
```

This problem usually arises for JDBC connectivity jars (MySQL, Derby, MSSQL, Oracle, etc.) or web MVC frameworks libraries like JSF or Spring MVC.

Take into account that some third party libraries rely on **other** third party libraries, so you have to add **all of them** in WEB-INF/lib in order to make the application work. A good example of this is RichFaces 4 libraries, [where you have to download and add the external libraries manually](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToAddRichFaces4xToProjectsNotBasedOnMaven).

---

Note for [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) users: you should not experience these problems unless you have set the libraries as `provided`, `test` or `system`. If set to `provided`, you're responsible to add the libraries somewhere in the classpath. You can find more info about the dependency scopes here: [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

---

In case the library must be shared among several applications that will be deployed on your application server e.g. MySQL connector for two applications, there's another alternative. Instead of deploying two war files each with their own MySQL connector library, place this library in the common library folder of the server application, this will enable the library to be in the classpath of all the deployed applications.

This folder vary from application server.

- Tomcat 7/8: `<tomcat_home>`/lib
- JBoss 7/Wildfly: `<jboss_home>`/standalone/lib

Comment: You forgot to mention where it's actually looking for the classes.

Answer (score 0):

The class must exist under WEB-INF/classes or be inside a .jar file under WEB-INF/lib. Make sure it does.

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware of that. Check my answer. Edit it accordingly if you think it misses anything.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happen with me.

Might be possible one of your libraries are using some classes internal which is not available

in your lib or maven dependency  pom.xml.

Thats means you have analyze your error logs and identify these classes and then import all dependencies in maven or lib folder.

I have fixed this error by the same way.

because some of my libraries are using activation.jar and json.jar internally.